# Sequelize - Model Setter Method is not working and I am getting no errors

Tags: jwt, sequelize.js

I am trying to generate a new token and store it in my database token table which is using MySQL as a DMS. I am generating the token using the jwt library. I am getting no errors and my generated token is not being generated. But the new user is being generated. This route handler function is responsible for creating a new user account. Which also creates a new token for that user to allow him/her to perform actions that requires authentication.

I tried using every possible way to set up a setter method for a model using sequelize. I read the docs and used both ways and none worked. The two ways are set() and setterMethod: ...code goes here. 
I also tried creating an instance and then accessing the setter method and that still didn't work. 
Lastly, I tried every possible way to get an error to display on the terminal by using try and catch block but I wasn't able to create it.
Just now, I tried to console.log "hello world" in the generateAuthToken setter method and I did not receive that message on the server. So, I think the problem has to do with the program not being able to recognize that function name.

Here is my token model and was defined by using the sequelize library:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const sequelize = require("../db/sequelize")

const User = require("./user");

const TokenSchema = sequelize.define("token", {
    userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'User',
          key: 'id'
        }
    },
    token: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'tokens',
    classMethods: {
        associate : function(models) {
          TokenSchema.belongsTo(models.User)
        }
    },
    setterMethods: {

        async generateAuthToken(user) {
              const token = await jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

              this.setDataValue('token', token);
              this.setDataValue('userId', user.id);

      }, 
    }
  })


module.exports = TokenSchema
```

Here is the user route that called the generateAuthToken setter method from the token model:

```
const express = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')
// const sharp = require('sharp')
const User = require('../models/user')
const Token = require('../models/token')

const auth = require('../middleware/auth')
const { sendWelcomeEmail, sendCancelationEmail } = require('../emails/sendEmail')
const router = new express.Router()

router.post('/users', async (req, res) => {

    const user = new User(req.body)

    try {
        await user.save()

        await Token.generateAuthToken(user.id)

        res.status(201).send({ user })

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send()
    }
})
```

The sad thing is that I am getting no errors. Which makes it so hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Your local copy of the `TokenSchema` is updated through your `generateAuthToken` method, but it is not persisted through the database. In other words, your Javascript object is updated, but you need to push it like so:

```
async generateAuthToken(user) {
    const token = await jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

    this.setDataValue('token', token);
    this.setDataValue('userId', user.id);

    await this.save();
}
```

Comment: That didn't fix it. Just now, I tried to console.log "hello world" in the generateAuthToken setter method and I did not receive that message on the server. So, I think the problem has to do with the program not being able to recognize that function name.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to fix it but I decided to just do it manually rather than calling a Sequelize setter method. It saved me a lot of time and it works perfectly fine. I just did it right in the route handler function but if you want to make your code more organize you could just create a util.js file that has all your functions that help you with certain things. Here is my code:

```
router.post('/users', async (req, res) => {

    const user = new User(req.body)

    try {
        await user.save()

        const generatedToken = await jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

        const token = new Token({ userId: user.id, token: generatedToken})

        await token.save();

        res.status(201).send({ user, token })

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```